# Why does my singing voice sound squeeky

Tags: voice, classical-music, voice-training, vocal-cords, voice-change

Most of the times I sing on pitch but still my singing sounds extremely dull. . How can I fix this ?

Comment: Thanks for contributing! I'm afraid a question-and-answer site isn't going to be very helpful to you, though. You're looking for help with tone, and the answer almost certainly is going to involve the whole way your body generates the sound—stance, breathing, and of course the shape of your mouth and vocal chords. It would be hard to say without actually hearing your tone and seeing you sing. You're looking for a teacher! Even if you aren't up for formal lessons right now, you could probably get some pointers by singing for friends who have had some training.

Comment: Also, I'll go ahead and offer one suggestion for free: I'm guessing the answer is "relax." It sounds like maybe you're "squeezing" and restricting your throat and vocal chords; instead, think of letting your throat "fall" open to let more air through. But better yet, get someone to give you pointers live.

Comment: Without evidence this question is pointless.

Comment: The best way to improve in any area of music is to hire a competent teacher.

Answer (score 1):

My recommendation is to reach out to every single performer and musician within your circle of friends and cohorts, and ask them point-blank; "How is my singing, and how do you recommend I improve it?"

The more we interact with other performers and musicians, the more we gain valuable feedback and advice. Tips, tricks, and thoughtful perspective.

Reach out.